# WebSocket with PHP - creating multiple functions

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I have set up Websocket (with Ratchet) on my local server. The chat messaging works fine but I'm trying to use it to fire 2 or 3 different functions to the client. Its pretty easy to get 1 function to work on the client side but I have 2 buttons for 2 different functions.
This is what I have.
index.php

```
    <input type="text" id="message" value="start" />
    <input type="text" id="testing" value="stop" />
    
    <button onclick="startThis()">Start Timer</button>
    <button onclick="stopThis()">Stop Timer</button>
    <script>
        // Create a new WebSocket.
        var socket  = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
        
        // Define the 
        var message = document.getElementById('message');
        var testing = document.getElementById('testing');
        
        function startThis() {
            socket.send( message.value );
            startTimer();    
        }
        
        function stopThis() {
            socket.send( testing.value );   
            stopTimer();  
        }
        
        
        socket.onmessage = function(e) { 
            alert( e.data ); 
            startTimer();
        }
        
        function startTimer() {
            
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "start timer";
            
        }
        
        function stopTimer() {

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "stop timer";
        }
        
    </script>
     
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

This is the call back from socket.php

```
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {

        foreach ( $this->clients as $client ) {

            if ( $from->resourceId == $client->resourceId ) {
                continue;
            }

            $client->send( "Client $from->resourceId wtf $msg" );
        }
    }
```

Functions function startThis() and function stopThis() work fine for the user but the problem I'm having is with the call back to the client

```
socket.onmessage = function(e) { 
            //alert( e.data ); 
            startTimer();
        }
```

so in my case startTimer gets called on the client side because I put that function inside socket.onmessage = function(e) but what I need is to be able to call either startTimer() or stopTimer() depending on the button the user clicks.

I have tried using if statements inside socket.onmessage = function(e) and in function startTimer() and function stopTimer() with no success.

Am I going about it wrong? Should I be editing the call back function in socket.php?
Any help[ would be much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be sending unstructured data to the client in the send() function so it'll be hard to parse and decide what to do. Maybe send some JSON back instead indicating the status

Comment: I would send some actual JSON and see if the clients get the proper message first. Let us know how that works

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a way to get want I need working. I changed the code block in socket.php to:

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {

        foreach ( $this->clients as $client ) {

            if ( $from->resourceId == $client->resourceId ) {
                continue;
            }

            **$client->send( "$msg" );**
        }
    }
```

In the index.php i made a change in the onmessage function:

```
socket.onmessage = function(e)  { 
                 
                if (e.data == "start") {
                    startThis();
                    
                } else if (e.data == "stop") {
                    stopThis();
                }
  
            }
```

and also in the index.php file I now just have to send 1 of the 2 different values to the socket.php file, start or stop

```
<input type="text" id="message" value="start" />
<input type="text" id="testing" value="stop" />

<button id="start" onclick="startTimer()">Start Timer</button>
<button id="stop" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop Timer</button>

<script>
    
    var socket  = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    
    // Define the 
    var message = document.getElementById('message');
    var testing = document.getElementById('testing');

    function startTimer() {
        socket.send( message.value );
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "start Timer";

    }
    
    function stopTimer() {
        socket.send( testing.value );  
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "stop Timer";  

    }
```

I'm sure there is a better way but being new to websocket I'll use this for the time being.

Please feel free to post better options.

Thanks